# Detached Mesh not moving properly with Armature

Tags: armature, weight-painting

I'm having an issue with detached mesh that is joined with a rigged mesh not moving fully with the Armature.

I have eyes joined with the head and when the head moves with the Armature the eyes will move with the head and then fall behind and come detached. The character has a "hat" on and that is detached from the mesh and moves perfectly with the rest of the mesh. The Eyes are fully weighted with the correct bone.

[image: Eyes are fully weighted and joined with the rest of the mesh.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the eye mesh, go into the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups*, remove the vertices from all groups, then select the group to which these vertices are supposed to be assigned and click on the *Assign* button:

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you. I'll remember this one. I come across this issue a lot.